# Cerrar Sesión después de un tiempo de inactividad en pantalla PHP

Tags: php, mysql, php7, login, sesiones

Estoy manejando inicios de sesiones en mi sistema de **PHP** con validación de usuarios. Pero me gustaría saber cómo puedo cerrar la sesión automáticamente **después de no haber actividad dentro de la pantalla.** De ser necesario, utilizando librerías externas, ¿o es simple programación de contador dentro del sistema?

Les dejo mi código.

**login.php:**

```php
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$secret = '6Lclh9EUAAAAAMmFZgmWeX6oa2qulKAdFghE04vh';

if (!$captcha) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Por favor verifica el captcha.");
  window.location.href="../login.php";
  </script>';
}

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha");

$arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);

if ($arr['success']) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where email = '$email' and password = '$password'";
    $bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar, $query);
    $parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($bdconect) > 0) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
      $_SESSION['name'] = $parametros['nombre_empresa'];
      $_SESSION['pin'] = $parametros['pin'];

      header("location: ../panel.php");
    } else {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrectos");
      window.location.href="../login.php";
      </script>';
    }
} else {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Error al verificar el captcha.");
  window.location.href="../login.php";
  </script>';
}
?>
```

**logout.php:**

```php
<?php
session_start(); // Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente
session_destroy(); // Destruye la sesión
header('location: ../login.php'); // Redirecciona la inicio
?>
```

Comment: Con un timmer de javascript y una llama ajax, solucionas el problema

Comment: Con actividad dentro de la pantalla te refieres a mover el mouse dentro de la pantalla como un evento también a considerar ?

Comment: @user3646126 así es

Answer (score 2):

Lo único que tenés que hacer es guardar la hora del último acceso en la sesión.
La próxima vez que el usuario haga una petición, controlas la hora actual contra la guardada y si supera el tiempo máximo establecido, cerrás la sesión en el servidor y devolves un mensaje acorde.

Nota: Cada vez que el usuario hace una petición que está dentro de la ventana de tiempo permitida, actualizas la hora del último acceso en la sesión.